# Изменить видимость DIV по ID из функции PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, друзья!
Пожалуйста, кому не лень, подскажите как изменить видимость блока по уникальному идентификатору.
Я пытался решить разными подходами, изменять на месте стиль отображения, постить атрибут элементу по ай-ди, не получается. Может, из-за того, что куски в разных файлах.

```
//index.php
<div id="ar_home_page" class="page_content">
    <? include'includes/ar_home.php'; ?>
</div>

<div id="market_page" class="page_content" style="display:none">
    <? include'includes/market.php'; ?>
</div>

//includes/nav.php
<li><a href="#" onclick=" магия, изменяющая видимость блоков: #ar_home_page скрыть, а #market_page показать ">Магазин</a></li>
```

Спасибо за ответы!
С уважением, Юра.

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос,можете описать детальнее чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Привет, quaresma89

Comment: Привет, quaresma89
Я, по своему сценарию, пока должен оставаться на этой странице. В меню есть ссылка (видна на коде), мне нужно по клику на неё скрыть первый див и показать второй (второй по умолчанию скрыт в файле style.css).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой совет: почитать про серверную часть кода, клиентскую. На момент, когда страница сгенерируется, серверный код, (пхп) уже отработает. Т.е. функция LoadMarket() отработает еще до клика по ссылке. Отсюда, необходимость реализовывать алгоритм приведенный в вопросе - отпадает. Резюмируя: все что мы пишем в серверном коде, в данном случае в `php` отработает еще **ДО** взаимодействия с пользователем. То есть с помощью `php` мы создаем страницу, как если бы мы написали ее "вручную", без использования сервера. Создаем на ней разметку, с каким-то функционалом и взаимодействием между элементами на **клиентском** уровне. То есть если мы в `php` хотим создать ссылку, по нажатию на которую нам бы вываливалось окошко с сообщением переменной, например равной `Hello World`, то использовали бы следующий код:

```
$someVar = 'Hello World';
echo "<a href='javascript:alert(\"$someVar\")'>Click me</a>"`.
```

---

Ввиду отсутствия смысла в этом, как такового, этими задачами должен заниматься клиент: `<li><a href="#" onclick="$('div.page_content').toggle()">Магазин</a></li>`

---

Либо, формируем странцу отталкиваясь от начальных параметров(в данном случае в запросе)

```
//php
$mode = $_GET('mode'); //Получаем параметр mode из ссылки
if($mode == 'market'){//проверяем его значение
    <?
        <div id="content_page" class="page_content">
            <? include'includes/market.php'; ?>
        </div>
    ?>
}else{
    <?
        <div id="content_page" class="page_content">
            <? include'includes/ar_home.php'; ?>
        </div>
    ?>
```

И получаем доступ к магазину из ссылки типа `.../index.php?mode=market`

---

Comment: Спасибо, костыль мне вполне подойдёт. Но что, в моём случае, some condition? Можно ли для равновесия второй костыль в навигаторе написать: <a onclick="<?$click=true?>">

Comment: @YuriMorozov, исправил ответ. Как оказалось, тут проблема даже глубже, чем просто костыльное решение. И если в ней разобраться, реализовывать подобные вещи будет куда проще.

Comment: О да! Вот я ту-ту, SLy_huh всё правильно подсказал. Я просто забыл об этом думать - различать сервер от клиента.

Comment: Спасибо SLy_huh, всё получилось. Главное, что я понял - как это делается.

Comment: @YuriMorozov, ну, собственно это те самые цели, которые мы преследовали, можете отметить вопрос закрытым, а ответ - верным `' 3'`